# Hibernate: Delete child row without affecting the parent

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

```
@Entity
class Parent {
    Long id;
}

@Entity
class Child {

    @ManyToOne
    Parent parent;  

}
```

Goal:
I need to delete a row from Child without attempting to delete the Parent.

Observation: The Child row is deleted, but an error is thrown that the Parent cannot be deleted, since other rows reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look something like this:

```
@Entity
class Parent {
Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

public void addChild( Child child )
{
    children.add( child );
    child.setParent( this );
}

public void removeChild( Child child )
{
    children.remove( child );
    child.setParent( null );
}

}

@Entity
class Child {

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
Parent parent; 

//important! implement hashCode and equals
```

}

if you want to remove a Child use removeChild on the Parent. (Also note, that the default FetchType on ManyToOne is EAGER.)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the thing is i cannot use two way relationship due to various reasons. But i solved the problem by adding `@Transactional `